# Php mysql left join no result issue

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

i've a query using left join, my problem is if right table is empty i cant get value which i'm using for ON clause, i mean;

```
   SELECT members.*,
          photos.* 
   FROM   members LEFT JOIN photos on members.member_id = photos.member_id
```

now, if it returns a result from photos table, its ok. But when there is no result from photos table, it returns from members table but it does not returns member_id. it returns all others from members table but not member_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you have two columns with the same name.

Try renaming one to avoid the collision:

`SELECT *, members.member_id AS real_member_id`

Comment: "*... you have two columns with the same name"* and somewhere between MySQL and your PHP code the two columns get distinguished by getting new names (probably both different than `member_id` :)

Comment: That work's thanks. I didnt use left join before so i try to match 2 tables with same column name.

Answer (score 2):

Give the `members.member_id` an alias name.

```
SELECT members.member_id as m_id, [other column you want] 
FROM members LEFT JOIN photos on members.member_id = photos.member_id
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `it returns all others from members table but not member_id`? Is it returning `(null)`? Basically yes it all returns all the records from the members table because you are joining it from the left (*members* table). But if the record from `member_id` does not exist, the it returns `null`. You have to give an `ALIAS` for that column since you have two fields with the same name.

```
members.member_id AS MemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to expicitedly write which columns you want in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT members.member_id
       members.name,
       photos.photo_id,
       photos.filename,
       ...
```

Then you can be sure that no 2 columns have the same name. It's also better because when one of the table's structure is changed, your query will break and you'll find out easily why. Now it was broken by working in an unexpected way.

---

If the only common column is `member_id` and you really need all the columns, this will work too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   members NATURAL LEFT JOIN photos
```